# A dense subset of a finite group

Tags: general-topology, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with Zariski topology. Suppose $G=A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n$, where $A_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, are pairwise disjoint subsets of $G$ and only $A_1$ is dense in $G$, that is, $A_i\subset \overline{A_1}$ for each $1\leq i\leq n$.

I don't know what is the mining of $``dense"$ in a finite set?

If there exist subgroups $C_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, such that $\frac{|G|}{|C_i|}=|A_i|$, can we say that $C_1$ is a subgroup of $C_i$ for $2\leq i\leq n$?

Comment: The definition gives you the meaning of dense - the closure is $G$.  The finiteness isn't relevant, this is purely topological. A subset $S$ of a topological space $X$ is dense if $\overline{S}=X$. Here you are taking the closure in the Zariski topology.

Comment: What is a "finite group with Zariski topology"? The only such things I know of are discrete.